# Как связать PostgreSQL с Spring приложением с помощью Docker

Tags: java, postgresql, spring, docker, gradle

Изучаю Docker. Хотел задеплоить Spring REST API с использованием PostgreSQL в Docker: Сначала я создал файл .jar с помощью jar и build tasks from Gradle.
Далее создал DockerFile -

```
FROM openjdk
ADD build/libs/PizzaApi-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar backend.jar
EXPOSE 5432
ENTRYPOINT ["java", "-jar", "backend.jar"]
```

Потом написал docker-compose.yml -

```
version: '3 '

services:
  postgers:
    image: 'postgres'
    environment:
      - 'POSTGRES_USER=postgres'
      - 'POSTGRES_PASSWORD=password'
      - 'POSTGRES_DB=pizzaapi'

  pizza-api:
    build: ./
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
    depends_on:
      - postgers
```

Исправил в файле application.properties localhost на postgres

```
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://postgres:5432/pizzaapi?useUnicode=true&useSSL=true&useJDBCCompliantTimezoneShift=true&useLegacyDatetimeCode=false&serverTimezone=UTC
spring.datasource.username=postgres
spring.datasource.password=Ubythfkbcbvec2
spring.jpa.generate-ddl=true
spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
spring.jpa.show-sql=false
spring.jpa.open-in-view=false
```

И вроде бы, всё должно работать, но нет.
При команде build запускаются 2 контейнера, где первый - postgres (он работает стабильно), а второй - PizzaApi (запускается, но скоро выходит с кодом ошибки 1). Ошибка возникает, вероятно, из-за соединения с базой данных.

Код ошибки вкратце -

```
 2022-10-18 18:05:13.516 ERROR 1 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool        : HikariPool-1 - Exception during pool initialization.
2022-10-18 18:05:15.146  WARN 1 --- [           main] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : SQL Error: 0, SQLState: 08001
2022-10-18 18:05:15.146 ERROR 1 --- [           main] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : The connection attempt failed.
2022-10-18 18:05:15.151 ERROR 1 --- [           main] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Failed to initialize JPA EntityManagerFactory: [PersistenceUnit: default] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.JDBCConnectionException: Unable to open JDBC Connection for DDL execution
2022-10-18 18:05:15.152  WARN 1 --- [           main] ConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: default] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.JDBCConnectionException: Unable to open JDBC Connection for DDL execution
2022-10-18 18:05:15.154  INFO 1 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Stopping service [Tomcat]
2022-10-18 18:05:15.165  INFO 1 --- [           main] ConditionEvaluationReportLoggingListener : 

Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2022-10-18 18:05:15.181 ERROR 1 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed
    
    org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: The connection attempt failed.
Caused by: java.net.UnknownHostException: postgres
```

Файл build.gradle -

```
plugins {
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '2.6.6'
    id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.0.11.RELEASE'
    id 'java'
}

group = 'com.example'
version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'

configurations {
    compileOnly {
        extendsFrom annotationProcessor
    }
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-security'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'
    implementation 'io.jsonwebtoken:jjwt:0.9.1'
    compileOnly 'org.projectlombok:lombok'
    runtimeOnly 'org.postgresql:postgresql'
    annotationProcessor 'org.projectlombok:lombok'
    testImplementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test'
    testImplementation 'org.springframework.security:spring-security-test'
}

tasks.named('test') {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}
```

Пытался я и так и сяк сделать - ни как не получается!(
Может я не указал то что обращаюсь именно к своей бд, или не указал порт для бд, или указал одинаковые порта для обоих бд. Но, я всё уже перепробовал. Уверен, ошибка ошивается где-то в docker-compose (pizza-api), либо в Dockerfile. Ведь на локальном хосту у меня всё запускается.

Последняя моё подозрение падает на сформированный jar файл, потому что в прочитанном мною примере он создавался в maven проекте, в директории target. У меня же он создаётся в папке build/libs/

Comment: У тебя в `depends-on` опечатка

Comment: И какую точно команду для запуска используешь? Д.б. `docker-compose up`

Comment: Ещё пароли в `docker-compose.yml` и `application.properties` разные

Answer (score 0):

у вас имя контейнера postgers а обращение postgres. Это опечатка:

```
services:
  postgers:
    ...
---
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://postgres:5432
```

Кроме того в environment:'POSTGRES_PASSWORD=password' один пароль, а в параметрах подключения другой spring.datasource.password=Ubythfkbcbvec2